# Copy and rename folder into another folder based on field value name

Tags: fso

I have this code, my objective is to copy and paste a folder (with all its content) from a current template folder to paste onto a destination file path that is based on the field values as a condition to the new file destination name.

I am receiving an error:

> FSO.CopyFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath

Not sure why, can you please help. Thank you.

```
Private Sub Command83_Click()
 Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String

    FromPath = "C:\Database Test Center\Master"  '<< Change
    ToPath = "C:\Database Test Center\Projects\" & Me.ProjectName.Value & "-" & 
Me.Lead.Value & "\MasterTemplate"

If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
    FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
End If

If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
    ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
End If

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
   End If

    FSO.CopyFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "You can find the files from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub
```

Comment: I am still getting an error on FSO.CopyFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath

Comment: Perhaps because I have many different files in the FromPath where its coping it to, there is different file extensions and sub folders.